# How make an int primary key based on bit shift

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-shift

I work on sql server and VB.net
I often use identity(1,1) on int primary key. 
But Today I want create a table to replace an enum. I use it in my programm like flags what can be adds (It's an enum about diseases, before I managed few diseases then You can have several diseases... but now I want to be able adds more diseases.)

I can do it in my vb codes, but I prefer my SQL server take care alone about his keys. But I don't find a way to say next key = last key << 1???

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The use of bit fields here seems like a premature optimization (and possibly not even that, since manipulating bit fields is slow and cumbersome in many modern architectures). Per Hickam's dictum: "a man can have as many diseases as he damn well pleases", though admittedly 32 would be a stretch.

Comment: We can use bigint too, but the list of disease will be restricted never more 15, it's just to prevent to go in my codes add disease in enum, rebuild it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a bit shift operator.
For as low as 15 records, I would recommend simply use a `tinyint` as your primary key and manually enter the values when you enter the next row.

You can have SQL Server compute it automatically for you, but that is an overkill to do it correctly.

**A naive approach** would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE disease 
(
    ident tinyint identity(1,1),
    name varchar(100),
    id AS (POWER(2, ident)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO disease (name) VALUES 
('flu'), ('diabetes'), ('tonsillitis')

SELECT id, name
FROM disease
```

Results:

```
id  name
2   flu
4   diabetes
8   tonsillitis
```

But it is naive because it assumes no gaps in the identity column. SQL Server does not guarantee that at all.

**In order to do it correctly** you will have to calculate the id column using a user defined function that will actually count the number of records entered before the current one, and then return the power of 2 by that number.
Please note that in this case you can't have the computed column persisted so it can't be the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE disease 
(
    ident tinyint identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100),
);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_CalculateDiseaseId 
(
    @ident tinyint
)
returns smallint
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN
    POWER(2, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM disease
        WHERE ident < @ident
    ) +1
    )

END;
GO


ALTER TABLE disease
    ADD id AS dbo.fn_CalculateDiseaseId(ident);
GO
```

same test as before:

```
INSERT INTO disease (name) VALUES 
('flu'), ('diabetes'), ('tonsillitis')


SELECT id, name
FROM disease
```

Results:

```
id  name
2   flu
4   diabetes
8   tonsillitis
```

[You can see a live demo of both on rextester.](http://rextester.com/MPRKP11656)

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2022, SQL does support functions to get/set bits, shift bits, and count bits.  These also exist in Azure SQL Database.  Under compatibility mode 160+, it also supports << and >> as well to achieve bit shifting.

[LEFT_SHIFT documenation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-shift-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)